# Java 8 grouping function to return Map<String, Integer> instead of Map<String,Long>

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am using the below mentioned code to find number of Times each word as occurred in a String.

```
Map<String, Long> map = Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s+")).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),LinkedHashMap::new,Collectors.counting()))
```

this code returns `Map<String, Long>` I want to transform this code to return `Map<String, Integer>`. I tried doing this by using the code below,

But It throws ClassCastException java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = 
 map.entrySet().parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> Integer.valueOf(entry.getValue())));
```

Please help me solve this, I need it to Return Map

Comment: Can you show the full statements? (including the variables you are assigning the results to).

Comment: `entry -> Integer.valueOf(entry.getValue()))` to `entry.getValue().intValue()`?

Comment: @Eran Please check the updates.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same on the first step itself rather than doing it afterwords, Is what I am looking at

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can perform a conversion of `Long` to `Integer` after the counting like

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s+"))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), Long::intValue)));
```

but you may also counting using an `int` value type in the first place:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s+"))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), LinkedHashMap::new,
        Collectors.summingInt(word -> 1)));
```

This is summing a one for each word. You can use the same approach with the `toMap` collector:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(text.split("\\s+"))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), word -> 1, Integer::sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must convert long to integer you need the value to be `o.getValue().intValue()`

```
Map<String, Integer> stringIntegerMap = 
stringLongMap.entrySet().stream().collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, o -> 
o.getValue().intValue(), (a, b) -> b));
```

There is a way you can first place convert as a `Map<String,Integer>` by `summingInt(x -> 1))`

```
 Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s+")).stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),LinkedHashMap::new,summingInt(value -> 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Collectors.counting()` is nothing more than `Collectors.reducing(0L, e -> 1L, Long::sum)` ([source](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collectors.java#l411)) ; use `Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)` instead and you'll be set :

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.asList(text.split("\\s+")).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Function.identity(),
    LinkedHashMap::new,
    Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)
));
```

[Try it here](https://ideone.com/E9ui5M).